# Building a jnlp from a jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm trying to pass dynamic arguments through the jnlp files using a jsp file to start my java application. However i'm really new to JWS so any help would be appreciated.

My question is, what should be in the test.jnlp for it to receive the parameters of username and pass the arguments into the java applciation? I've read many others posts but i still can't get my application to receive the arguments.

Current Code:

JNLP.JSP

```
   <% 
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"bb.jnlp\";");
response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
      codebase=<%=request.getScheme() + "://"+ request.getServerName() + ":" 
+ 
request.getServerPort()+ request.getContextPath() + "/" %> 
      href="test.jnlp&#063;username=<%=request.getParameter("username")%>">
    <information>
        <title>ProBuilder</title>
        <vendor>pAtoms</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
        <description>ProBuilder</description>
    </information>
    <security>
    <sandbox/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="ProBuilder.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="adam.Adam" >
       <argument><%=request.getParameter("username")%></argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your servlet class obtain parameters:

```
String username = req.getParameter("username");
String pass = req.getParameter("pass");
```

Assuming `req` is `HttpServletRequest`, if you want secure application then better somehow secure your password.

Set attributes in your request:

```
req.setAttribute(username, "username");
req.setAttribute(pass, "pass");
```

and dispatch your attributes to jnlp

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("jnlp.jsp").forward(req, YOUR_HttpServletResponse);
```

In your jsp obtain attributes like that:

```
${requestScope.username}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think i need to read up on jnlp and how servlet interact with one other to make full use it.